# Can Spring 5 allow POST in jsp without controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know this Spring MVC blasphemy, but I'm trying to use a non-Spring jsp that calls itself and checks if the RequestMethod is POST.  Spring 5 doesn't seem to like POST calls back to a jsp.  Is this possible with something like:

`<mvc:view-controller path="/admin/logManager" requestMapping="{RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}" />`

I also tried 'method' replacing 'requestMapping'

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use jsps without Spring but to use Spring MVC without the C doesn't makres sense. Maybe you are looking for the PRG-Pattern?

Comment: The jsp was created of hybrid java & html.  It uses java code to display html options and on submit calls itself again.  The submit is POST and the jsp, through the java, conditionally checks if the call to itself was made through POST.  I know I can rewrite as MVC but I'm just trying to reuse existing non-Spring jsp.  Thanks.